# SERVER2012 R2 Core access denied when deploying domain controller from remote system

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, deployment

I have installed Windows Server 2012r2 Core edition and want to promote it to my first domain controller. I intended to do this with a Server Manager installed on a client computer.

I connected to the server with the Server Manager and was able to install the AD DS role and the DNS role. After installation when I want to deploy the Domain Controller however I get an error:

> An unexpected error occured while trying to configure AD DS. Error
>   encountered while trying to get the domain information. Access is
>   denied

This happens while using the same user that was used to install the roles.

The server IP has been set to static, the DNS server points to itself, client and server are part of the same workgroup. I tried with RSAT tools in both Windows 8.1 and 10.

As a stop gap I installed the Server Manager on the server itself and from there I can deploy the Domain controller. However, I would like to understand why it is not working from the remote system.

All is done in virtual machines (not actual hardware) and I can therefore go back to the state before deployment.

Comment: From what account did you start server manager from on the client device?

Comment: On the client I use a local admin account. Since this is my first DC I can not use domain users. In the server list I right click the server and select "Manage As" to manage it with the administrator account from the server. However a look at the eventviewer on the server has shown me that it appears to ignore the user I'm managing it with and attempts to login with my local account (which off course is unknown).

Comment: So, I've been digging a little deeper and it seems that when I launch the deployment wizard on the remote client from it's server manager the wizard attempts to log in with the client's local credentials instead of using the credentials that the server manager knows for the server. And given that the client account has no admin rights on the server you get an access denied. Only option left is to deploy the domain controller trough powershell (or a local gui on the server).

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following command in PowerShell on the remote computer accessing the server

```
cmdkey /add:servername /user:username /pass:password
```

it should fix your problem.